# Creating eclipse source files src/main/java and src/main/groovy with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, groovy

I am trying to get a specific kind of file structure in eclipse for my work.
This is the structure I want:

[image: fileStructure2]

The problem I am having is that everytime I use `mvn eclipse:eclipse` the structure of the files gets broken like this:

[image: fileStructure1]

I have tried most of the answers that I've found on Stack Overflow and elsewhere. I've tried making the fileStructure2 to a maven Archetype and it sort of worked, but as soon as I ran `mvn eclipse:eclipse` it broke again:

[image: arcTesting]

I learned the basics of the archetype creation just today so I am not a master at that either and there might be something that is missing from the creation of the archetypes. I used `mvn archetype:create-from-project` in the FileStructure2 directory and then used `mvn install archetype:update-local-catalog` in the archetype directory which resulted the archetype to be added in the list of archetypes and I just created a new project with cmd and then ran `mvn eclipse:eclipse` which resulted in the above picture. I have not changed anything in the archetype folders that were created, I just used the basic ones that were created with running the archetype:create.

Most of the other posts i've found are really old and none of them have the structure I want, or it is only for src/main/java which I get working as intended but it is just the src/main/groovy file that switches the location to a normal folder instead of a source folder.

I am thinking it is my pom.xml that needs some modifications. at the moment it looks like this:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>FileStructure</groupId>
  <artifactId>FileStructure</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <type>pom</type> <!-- required JUST since Groovy 2.5.0 -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>  
</project>
```

I have not added any maven compiler plugins since I don't 100% know what they do and still break the structure no matter what I've tried.

I am using apache-maven-3.8.5 which is downloaded with chocolatey. My eclipse jre and jdk versions are 1.8.0_333 but my java home is jdk11 since sonarQube can't use that old versions. My groovy is downloaded from the eclipse marketplace and it's compiler version is 2.5. My eclipse is a SAP netweaver. Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

I have converted the projects to maven and groovy via Eclipse's own methods.

Comment: First I would ask why combination of Java and Groovy and not plain Java...and simply create the structure on the disk? Furthermore You are using extreme old tools (Oxygen is of 2017??? really?) Why using [maven-eclipse-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/)  is long retired. First use uptodate tools (IDE's Eclipse) and modern JDK's...And as you also realized SonarQube can handle that anymore because that needed JDK11 at least...

Comment: @khmarbaise It would otherwise be plain java but the server side coders had made groovy files and we wanted to start testing them and testing them needed both the java files and the groovy files. We are using older jdk since some of the libraries from SAP don't work on the newer ones. For the old version of IDE, this was just given to me as a package by work, that I downloaded and I didn't start questioning about it.

Comment: The problem with such old software (Eclipse Oxygen is now 5 years and 17 releases old) is that people don't remember how things worked so long ago.

Comment: I'll look into upgrading the software, maybe it'll fix my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Groovy Development Tools will do this. There is a guide here with steps to achieve your desired result:

https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/Groovy-Eclipse-Maven-plugin

There is an archetype as well but it is not pre-built:  https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/tree/master/extras/groovy-eclipse-quickstart